# Display size issue in elemantary os

Tags: release-freya

When I login in my elementary OS system my display size is set too large. My graphics are Intel(R) G33/G31 Express Chipset Family.

Comment: Did you try to change the resolution inside System Settings > Displays ??

Answer (score 1):

Try install latest Linux kernel with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kernel-ppa/ppa
sudo apt update 
sudo apt upgrade
```

Or latest elementary OS, because with this chip everything should work

Comment: Adding a different version of the kernel than the one that comes with Ubuntu LTS could introduce new problems. That's totally fine if you want to live on the bleeding edge, but a disclaimer would be helpful here. :)